# xticks on only bin ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, xticks

I have a dataframe with datetime data, whose columns tell how many days are from various holidays. I'd like to create histograms of that data, and I tried the following code:

```
holiday_features = [name for name in df.columns if 'DAYS FROM' in name]
for feature in holiday_features:
    plt.hist(df[feature], bins=12)
    plt.title(feature)
    plt.xticks(rotation=60)
    plt.show()
```

When I created that loop, histograms like the following appeared:

[image: DAYS FROM NEW YEARS histogram]

It appears that the ticks represent every single feature, rather than just the bins. Blowing up the histogram to obscene proportions confirms this:

[image: plt.figure(figsize=(70,70))]

I'm just interested in bin ticks, not the feature ticks. How do I remove those ticks to make a neater histogram?

Comment: Looks like you are plotting an histogram for each feature on the same `matplotlib` figure. Try adding `plt.figure()` before you call `hist`. For understanding how to set custom `xticks` you can refer to the many examples on SO e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46231439/problems-with-matplotlib-pyplot-xticks)

Comment: @JacoSolari I get what you're saying, but I only provided the first of the series. All of the histograms look like this one. Regarding that particular issue, `plt.show()` actually effectively breaks the cycle so the histograms don't all produce on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use [subplots](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html), and operate the xticks on the [Axes](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?) class.

For example, for a single plot:

```
_, axis = plt.subplots(1, 1) # create an Axes class for a single plot
axis.hist(data, bins=12)
axis.set_xticklabels(axis.get_xticks(), rotation=60)
plt.show()
```

The code above produces a plot with the following aesthetic:

[image]

Additionally, considering that, in your case, you are plotting many features, you could produce a grid of plots using the subplots function, as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import seaborn as sns

holiday_features = [name for name in df.columns if 'DAYS FROM' in name]

# define number of rows and columns to the subplot
ncols = 3  # considering a grid with 3 plots per row
nrows = int(np.ceil(len(holiday_features)/3))

# create subplots
_, axes = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols)
axes = axes.flatten()

# plot features with rotated ticks
for j, feature in enumerate(holiday_features):
    axes[j].hist(df[feature], bins=12)
    axes[j].set_title(feature)
    axes[j].set_xticklabels(axes[j].get_xticks(), rotation=60)
    
# remove empty plots
for k in range(j, len(axes)):
    sns.despine(ax=axes[k], top=True, right=True, left=True, bottom=True)
    axes[k].xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.NullFormatter())
    axes[k].xaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
    axes[k].yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.NullFormatter())
    axes[k].yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')

# show plot
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```