# I am having issues Increasing the space between my x axis labels and also increasing its size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

I have successfully plotted my line graph as a newbie,but struggling to increase the space between my x axis labels and also the size because they are overlapping.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
x  = state_query_df['location_id']
y1 = state_query_df['Population']
y2 = state_query_df['professionals']
plt.plot(x, y1, label="Population", linewidth = 3)
plt.plot(x, y2, label="Professionals",linewidth = 3)

plt.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', labelsize=10)

plt.xlabel("location_id")
plt.ylabel("Population")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is `geo_id` supposed to be a string?  Or is it supposed to be treated as a number?  If you treat as a string you will get a tick for each unique string in the order they are read.  If you treat as a number the ticks will be determined automatically.    If you want to drop some of the tick labels you can do that.  If you want to rotate the tick labels you can also do that.  But its not entirely clear from your description what is desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Change Figure Size and xticks:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.figure(figsize=(20,8)) ## figure size change from 10x8 to 20x8
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 10, step=2.5))  ## xticks change 
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage to do this with the command xticks

Check out this post:
[Problems with matplotlib.pyplot.xticks()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46231439/problems-with-matplotlib-pyplot-xticks)

Update:
This probably happens because you assign on x-axis the values of the first curve and the values of the second curve, as well. Try either removing the values of the one of the two x-axis OR assign your own with command xticks.